# Leaving Brazil without entry form

Tags: customs-and-immigration, borders, brazil

When arriving to Brazil, I had to fill the customs declaration and entry form. The entry form then was stamped and returned to me. I was told, that this piece of paper is very important and that I need to return it when I leave the country.

What would happen, if I didn't have the form when leaving Brazil? For example in case I lost it or if they forgot to give me the form when I enter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this link](http://natalinformation.com/com/index.php/Arrival_in_Natal/), which explains what could happen if the entry form is not presented when leaving Brazil.

> Loss of the Arrival/Departure Card can cause many problems with the customs at departure. In case of loss you can expect a fine of R$150,= (about € 60,= or $ 100,=). If there are problems, remember the majority only speak Portuguese!

I myself heard different things:

- when I was crossing border from Argentina at Foz do Iguaçu, they didn't even give me the form to fill. Only when I asked for it. They said something, that they assumed I'd be leaving also in Foz.
- I talked to a person working for our consulate. She said that once they received a call from one citizen asking for assistance (also in Foz do Iguaçu), because he lost his form and got into troubles with *Policia Federal*, which I understand is responsible also for immigration and customs in Brazil.